# How does Bloc's EventTransformer works?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I really don't understand how the `EventTransformer` works in bloc library. I need to know this info because I may need to implement a custom transformer in my apps. For example, this custom transformer

```
EventTransformer<RegistrationEvent> debounceRestartable<RegistrationEvent>(
    Duration duration,
  ) {
    return (events, mapper) => restartable<RegistrationEvent>()
        .call(events.debounceTime(duration), mapper);
  }
```

makes `RegistrationEvent`s restartable (i.e. "process only one event by cancelling any pending events and processing the new event immediately."),
and this transformer also creates a "guard time" between events so that if two `RegistrationEvent`s arrive in duration interval less than `duration`, only one will be processed.

But I don't understand from the documentation how is this code doing this?